# Create a connection to a DBMS in R

Tags: r, database, monetdblite

I'm using the libraries `DBI` to create a connection to a `monetdblite` database in R but I keep getting the same error. Here is the reproducible example and the error message I get. Any ideas on how to solve this ?

```
# Load Packages
  library(MonetDB.R)
  library(MonetDBLite)
  library(survey)
  library(DBI)

# Load Data
  data(api)


# create survey design
  dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

# create Temp dir.
  dbfolder <- tempdir()

# create connection
  db <- dbConnect( MonetDBLite() , dbfolder )
```

> Error in MonetDBLite::monetdb_embedded_startup(embedded, !getOption("monetdb.debug.embedded",  : 
>    unused argument (getOption("monetdb.sequential", TRUE))

As additional info, I'm using:

- R 3.2.4revised
- latest Rstudio 0.99.893
- Windows 10

Comment: hi, try again with `MonetDBLite` on CRAN, which replaces `MonetDB.R` and runs embedded (like `RSQLite`).  for more detail, see https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please update your MonetDB.R and MonetDBLite packages, there has been a recent API change

```
install.packages(c("MonetDB.R", "MonetDBLite"), 
  repos=c("https://dev.monetdb.org/Assets/R/", "http://cran.rstudio.com/"))
```